# Mapping Entity Related fields to Sitecore from Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

I have an XML here,

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="sample_Related" from="sam_account" to="accountid" link-type="inner" alias="aa">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="SampleAttr" operator="not-null" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

I am trying to map the field `SampleAttr` to the Account entity since I am calling a batch pipeline for account that has a field from `sample_Related`, is there a way for me to map it on Sitecore?

Comment: Could you please check this article [https://www.codinglittlethings.com/2019/06/sitecore-9-dynamic-crm-connector-sync.html](https://www.codinglittlethings.com/2019/06/sitecore-9-dynamic-crm-connector-sync.html)?

Comment: Hi, i checked it and i'm looking for a solution that utilize the use of Data Exchange Framework for mapping.. thank you.